# TYPO3: Adding new fields for tt_content has problems with new content elements from extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-gridelements

I have written the TYPO3 extension "cewrap", which adds new fields to table tt_content. Problem is, when installing an extension which introduces new content elements (e.g. EXT:gridelements) and this extension is loaded **after** my extension (because of its position in PackageStates.php), the fields from my extension are missing in the new content elements.

Is there a solution for that problem?
Is there a way to affect the order of the entries in PackageStates.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the packages you want to come *before* your own package, as entries in the `suggest` properties of composer and TER manifests, should sort them as such in `PackageStates.php`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. But a more general way would be better, I don't want to add all extensions, which provide new content elements, in "suggest".